# How can I make a Client host a game between 2 Clients instead of Server hosting it

Tags: java, client-server, multiplayer

Such as Call of Duty and Halo does, how would I go about creating games that I don't host? how could I have one of the clients that has connected to my Server host a game to save space on my server?

I don't have any attempts, because I'm not sure how the logic plays out. My closest guess would be that you have to somehow re-establish a separate, private connection between the 2 clients. But I myself have to make sure I port-forward and host on the correct port to ensure people can connection, so I don't know how I could set up that type of system.

So basically:
2 Clients connect to server
Server creates a game, but doesn't wanna handle the data between the 2
Server picks a client to host the game, that game relies on that host's connection

Comment: You should start by moving all server game logic to client code (while still retaining abstraction and organization) so a client can act in a per-game server role. Once you try that, ask here with specific things you come across. As for port issues, look into "UDP holepunching" where your server is used as a "rendezvous point" to establish the link.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem in networking. The most common solution is what is employed in VoIP infrastructures for P2P calls. So as you mentioned there is a central server which clients connect to and then the players from then on manage the communication i.e. media or game data transfer on their own.

The central server in this case is in charge of signaling and introducing the players. The communication parameters are negotiated over the central server. Common protocols for doing this are SIP and for negotiating ports and IP addresses - the body of the SIP messages will contain SDP messages. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol

Specifically for NAT traversal the industry standard is ICE
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment

Do note that a comprehensive implementation of the above mentioned protocols and standards is not an easy task at all as there are several network configurations possible. So I'd recommend you use the above to understand the complexity of your scenario. Then depending on what you feel - implement the parts you feel are important.

Alternatively, don't discard the possibility of going have a central server handling the data. It keeps things a lot simpler.